# Get [object Object] instead of real new element on the current markup

Tags: javascript

I'm totally newbie...trying to make a study project.
Have a page with 6 initialed cards. Card consist of picture and text, under this picture.
Have a button, using for add new card.
Trying to use OOP, I make a class Card for get a template and return it with data. And its work. But, the button doesnt work. When I try to add new card, I get [object, Object] instead of new card.
this is my class Card:

```
class Card {
  constructor(cardData, cardSelector) {
    this.name = cardData.name;
    this.link = cardData.link;
    this.cardSelector = cardSelector;
  }
  _getView() {
    this.element = cardTemplate.querySelector('.place').cloneNode(true);
    const cardImage = this.element.querySelector('.place__image');
    const cardName = this.element.querySelector('.place__name');
    cardImage.src = this.link;
    cardImage.alt = this.name;
    cardName.textContent = this.name;
    this.cardImage = cardImage;
    this.cardName = cardName;
    this._setEventListeners();
    return this.element;
  }
  _setEventListeners() {
    this.element.querySelector('.place__button-remove').addEventListener('click', () => this._removeCard());
    this.element.querySelector('.place__button-like').addEventListener('click', () => this._likeCard());
    this.element.querySelector('.place__image').addEventListener('click', () => this._openCardPreview());
  }
  _removeCard() {
    this.element.remove();
  }
  _likeCard() {
    this.element.querySelector('.place__button-like').classList.toggle('button_type_like-active');
  }
  _openCardPreview() {
    openPopup(popupImage);
    popupPic.src = this.cardImage.src;
    popupPic.alt = this.cardName.textContent;
    popupName.textContent = this.cardName.textContent;
  }
}
```

And this is small function for adding card:

```
function addNewCard(addingCard) {
  cardsArray.prepend(addingCard);
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting that? `[object Object]` happens when you try to use an object as a string.

Comment: What is the value of `addingCard`? `prepend()` expects its argument to be either a DOM element or text. If `addingCard` is an object, it will be converted to text, and you'll get `[object Object]`. I think it should be `cardsArray.prepend(addingCard.element)`

Comment: But if it's an instance of `Card`, I think you should actually be getting `[object Card]`. So I'm not sure what `addingCard` is.

Comment: Hm, cheked, and I'm afraid, `addingCard` is not used. So, I dont understand what I need to transfer to function. Think I need an another method for class? or somehow use `this.element` for that

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.